# Docker in Docker: Port Mapping

Tags: docker

I have found a similar thread, but failed to get it to work. So, the use case is

I start a container on my Linux host

```
docker run -i -t --privileged -p 8080:2375 mattgruter/doubledocker
```

When in that container, I want to start another one with GAE SDK devserver running.

At that, I need to access a running app from the host system browser.

When I start a container in the container as

```
docker run -i -t -p 2375:8080 image/name
```

I get an error saying that 2375 port is in use. I start the app, and can curl 0.0.0.0:8080 when inside both containers (when using another port 8080:8080 for example) but cannot preview the app from the host system, since lohalhost:8080 listens to 2375 port in the first container, and that port cannot be used when launching the second container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do that using the image [jpetazzo/dind](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jpetazzo/dind/). The test I have done and worked (as an example):

1. From my host machine I run the container with docker installed:

   `docker run --privileged -t -i --rm -e LOG=file -p 18080:8080
   jpetazzo/dind`
2. Then inside the container I've pulled nginx image and run it with

   `docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx`

And from the host environment I can browse the nginx welcome page with http://localhost:18080

With the image you were using ([mattgruter/doubledocker](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mattgruter/doubledocker/)) I have some problem running it (something related to log attach).